how to split a single payment across several invoices for several customers
I have a vendor who collects payments from my customers for me and makes a single deposit every fortnight.
I have several customers with fortnightly invoices.
The customers tend to pay irregular amounts so most payments are partial payments for one or two invoices.
I don't seem to be able to have gnucash split the vendor's payment across several customers' invoices.
Can anyone recommend an account/split structure (or whatever) that would let me split the deposits as payments to invoices for several customers?
Update: I vaguely remember a technique involving an intermediate account for a similar but slightly different problem, but cannot for the life of me find the right search terms to find that technique explained again.
I figure I might be able to split the payments into another account (what type?) and then use that account as the transfer account for payments entered manually.

I've setup an account structure that seems to work:

Assets

Current
Accounts_Receivable

Customer_1
...
Customer_N




Liabilities

Payments

Customer_1
...
Customer_N




Income

Customer_1
...
Customer_N



Invoice line items are attributed to Income:Customer_X.
Invoices are posted to Assets:Accounts_Receivable:Customer_X.
Deposits in Assets:Current are split into Liabilities:Payments:Customer_X
Customer_X's invoice payments are transferred from Liabilities:Payments:Customer_X.
So, payments show as a liability until an equivalent value assigned as a payment to an invoice.
This itself is useful to show me if there are payments made but not assigned to an invoice or if there are over payments.

Criticism of this approach would be appreciated.
